# how to write a query to parse a column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table tb1(item, status), status is `varchar(50)`. For instance,

```
item    status
item1   abc
item2   a
item3   ed
item4   ca
```

I need to write a query to select those items whose status has a value that is any of ('b', 'd', 'f'). So the result should be `item1, item3`. How do I write a query to split the column status?

Comment: How do you figure that item2 and item3 are being retrieved?

Comment: How the result would be item2?

Comment: `item2` has only `a`. So how would that be in your result?

Comment: Sorry. The result should be item1 and item3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select item, status
from tb1
where status like '%[bdf]%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8824b/1)

Comment: I think he wants exact values.

Comment: @RezaSadr That's not what your query is doing ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from yourTable
where Contains(status, 'b OR d OR f')
```

see here the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

Comment: This would require the table `tb1` to be full-text indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 
WHERE status LIKE '%a%' OR status LIKE '%b%' OR status LIKE '%f%'
```